# SMW: No form widgets for record fields?

Tags: mediawiki, records, semantic-mediawiki

I'm experienced with MediaWiki but pretty new to the SMW extension.
What I try to realize is a wiki to maintain accesspoints that contain e.g. antenna configuration.

So we got an template:accesspoint

```
{| class="wikitable"
! ID
| [[Antenna::{{{ant|}}}]] 
|}
```

and an attribute:antenna that holds opening and direction angles

```
[[Datentyp::record]]
[[has fields::number; number]]
```

To make it comfortable for the users, I like to create a form to enter the values, but unfortunately I can't pick an widget that represents the antenna record values. All I can choose is the choice inputtype = hidden :-(

Also after browsing a lot of tutorials I can't say if there is just a config or syntax problem, or if I just picked the wrong way to model composed data in an object centred way?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use the much more flexible subobjects, rather than the old record type. Also, please state the SMW/SF versions!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip! I thought [subobjects](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Adding_subobjects) aren't a good solution, but will give it a try :-)

This is MW 1.24 and SMW / bundle 1.9.2

Comment: Ok, then you are using a fairly old version of SMW. You might want to upgrade. In recent versions, the record type is stored as a subobject behind the scenes, which might make things easier.

Comment: PS. Also from the docs: `Though the Record type still exists, it has major problems in flexibility and queriability, and should simply be avoided.`

Comment: @Mam, please let us know if you found a solution.